# Why can't my sisters heal?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Sometimes when my Sisters turn arrives they can use their heal ability; sometimes they can't. I can't quite figure out when they can and when they can't. Seems they can only use it once per turn, but sometimes even when a fresh turn starts they can't.

Does anybody know the rules behind this thing? Nowhere in the description does it mention any limitation or mana cost or anything...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They can only use the ability twice per battle.  You should see a little number over the skill that tells how many casts you have left for the current battle.

In addition, if your sisters get an extra action due to good morale, they will not be able to use their ability during the extra action.  Attacks/movement during the extra action is only 50% of what it would normally be, and you are not allowed to use skills.  You can however use the heal as their normal action, and then use the extra action to attack/move as normal.

Answer (score 3):

They can only use their heal twice per combat. (And as you said once per round)
If you look at the icon there is a number which indicates how many uses you have left.

Comment: I'm playing the demo, and no numbers appear... I guess the demo is broken.

Comment: @Oak Yes, this was a bug that was fixed in one of the early patches, but I don't think the patches are being applied to the demo.